# I Need Create Cookie On Domain And Get It On subdomain

Tags: php, cookies, dns, subdomain

I'm with an difficult to create cookie an domain and use it another subdomain.

I'm trying set cookie whith this code:

```
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", "mydomain.com.br");

setcookie("test", "test_value", time()+3600);
```

And get cookie whith this code on my subdomain(subdomain.mydomain.com.br):

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_COOKIE);
print_r($_SERVER ['HTTP_COOKIE']);
die("</pre>");
```

What I did wrong? rs

Comment: Unless the subdomain has its own cookie with the same name, it should inherit the cookie from the parent domain automatically. You don't need to do anything special.

Comment: But not work. What the best way to get the cookie on subdomain?

Comment: Depending on the age of your browser, you may need a leading period ( . ).  And you can do this all with `setcookie()`

`setcookie("test","test_value",time()+3600,'/','.mydomain.com.br')`

Comment: `session.cookie_domain` specifies the domain value PHP uses when working with _sessions_, it applies to the cookie that stores the session id - which is not what you are doing here, you are using `setcookie` to create your _own_ cookie, which has nothing whatsoever to do with PHP’s session mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this:

```
setcookie();
setcookie("test","test_value",time()+3600,'/','.mydomain.com.br');
```